# Matching list to dict and then loop, store and display

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to pull a the value from the list `S` and match it to the dictionary `Cost` and I am just need help grasping the syntax for this. Its supposed to take your input, check it to the `CostDict` and output the `V` then it will check to see if it can be purchased 5 times, if it can it will randomly purchase between 1 and 5 of them, check to see if there is leftover money and continue purchasing between 1 and 5 of them or just 1. But I am getting errors on this and it is pretty confusing for me.

```
from collections import Counter


i = input('Taco, Burrito or Nacho: ')
moneyi = input('How much Money to Spend: ')
money = float(moneyi)

S = ["Taco", "Burrito", "Nacho"]
V = [6, 4, 2]
CostDict = {Li: Prop for (Li, Prop) in zip(S, V)}
cost = CostDict[i]
print("Costs:" + str(cost) + " per")
if (cost * 5) < money:
    purchase_ls = []
    while money >= min(cost):
        b = randint(1, 5)
        bcost = (CostDic[S] * b)
        bvalue = (ValueDic[S] * b)
        for aProp in S:
            if money < int(cost[S.index(aProp)]):
                continue
            purchase_ls.append(aProp)
            vcost = int(bcost[S.index(aProp)])
            money = money - bcost
            print("item: {} cost: {} money you have: {} ".format(aProp, vcost, money))
            if money <= 0:
                break
    print(dict(Counter(purchase_ls)))
else:
    purchase_ls = []
    while money >= min(cost):
        bcost = (CostDic[S])
        bvalue = (ValueDic[S])
        for aProp in S:
            if money < int(cost[S.index(aProp)]):
                continue
            purchase_ls.append(aProp)
            vcost = int(bcost[S.index(aProp)])
            money = money - bcost
            print("item: {} cost: {} money you have: {} ".format(aProp, vcost, money))
            if money <= 0:
                break
    print(dict(Counter(purchase_ls)))
```

Comment: can you post your specific error message here?

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable at line 14

Comment: Thanks! The best way to do this is to post the entire error trace from your terminal into your original post -- it will indicate at which point this fails, etc. Just the above is not that indicative.

Comment: `min(cost)` returns the smallest value from an iterable of values, but `cost` is just an `int`. Did you mean to just say `cost` instead of `min(cost)`?

Comment: probably, tbh i am about 44 hrs in on not sleeping to try to get this project finished and its... creeping up one me :(

Comment: everything looks easy once you get some sleep! until then, try @dtanabe comment